# Can't access my locally installed Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp

I am running xampp, and I want to have multiple websites in the htdocs folder. When I just install Wordpress into the htdocs folder, it works fine. However, when I clone (from github) a pre-existing build of wordpress and place it into the htdocs folder (ex - htdocs/somesite.com) I cannot access it.

I get an error of:

> Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite.com/wp-includes/load.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite.com\wp-settings.php on line 21
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite.com/wp-includes/load.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite.com\wp-settings.php on line 21

I am confused on two things:

1. I see the file there that is SAYS is missing in the directory. This I have triple and quadruple checked. I also do not understand the reference to the c:\xampp\php\PEAR path
2. I also do not know whether or not there are problems coming from the fact that the slashes between directories changing direction are causing the problem. Like why are they starting off with the "\" but then going to "/" after the "mysite.com".

This is the second time I have run into this problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Place it in the Wordpress file within htdocs?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: `c:\xampp\php\PEAR` is just your `php.ini` configured `include_path`. I wouldn't worry about it or the type of slash. What version of Wordpress is it?

Comment: Im not sure. Where would I find that?

Comment: However, the error I am getting now is "unable to establish database connection". The database is hosted in AWS and there is no way I can replicate it because I do not have access to it via any admin

Comment: The version is in `wp-includes/version.php`. How did it start working? What did you change? If the database connection is an issue, check the settings in `wp-config.php`

Comment: it's 4.5.3 and I did not change a thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)